# Can we use same WASM and State files for registering parathread on Kusama, which we used for Rococo?

Tags: polkadot, kusama, rococo

We generated WASM and State files to submit on Rococo. It went fine and we get successfully registered as parachain on Rococo.

Can we use the same WASM and State files for registering parathread on Kusama, which we used for Rococo?

Or

We need to generate again on our mainnet server, which we are using to integrate with Kusama.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can we use the same WASM and State files for registering parathread on Kusama, which we used for Rococo?

Yes, technically you can do this. Assuming you have the same `ParaId` on both networks it should work flawlessly. However, you should be aware that this then may leads to your two networks to join, because both are using the same genesis hash. I mean the will not really join, but nodes from one network may connect to node of the other network. It could lead to some confusion. However, if you only had deployed for testing on Rococo and shut down everything again, this should not happen.

Answer (score -2):

If you look in the cumulus repo at statemint, you'll see how we set out westmint, statemine and statemint as separate runtimes.

There are going to be different assumptions and constants in the different relay chains so one would want to benchmark each runtime separately, and thus you would want separate runtimes.

You can still extract common values to avoid repeating yourself. E.g. https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/blob/master/polkadot-parachains/parachains-common/src/lib.rs